# MIPS: Figuring out a Jump instruction code

Tags: mips

I'm trying to figure out how to create a jump instruction code and have the right code, but I'm not sure why.

So, if I have this:

```
        addi $s1, $s1, 0 
        addi $s1, $s1, 0
        lui $s1, 0x1001
top:    bne $s1, $s2, end
        addi $s1, $s1, 1
end:    j   top
```

I want to figure out the jump instruction for `j top`

The correct answer is 0x08100003. I'm just not sure how.

The address of top is 0x0040000C.

A quick and dirty way to calculate this is so figure out x * 4 = target address. So, x * 4 = 4 (1) and x * 4 = 12 (3). So, I see why there is a 1 and a 3 in the instruction.

The opcode for jump is 2hex, so we start with 0000 10 (the 6 bits for the opcode). Then I'm not sure what to do next. I knew the end of the instruction is going to be 3, but how would I know where to place the 1?

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

The instruction word for `J` consists of a 6-bit opcode with the value `%000010`, followed by 26 bits that contains the lower 28 bits of the target address shifted right by 2 bits.

If we take `0x040000C`, shift it right by 2 bits and display the result in binary form with only the lower 26 bits we get `%00000100000000000000000011`.

Let's prepend the opcode bits to that, which gives us `%00001000000100000000000000000011`. If we split that number into groups of four bits it'll be easier to see the hexadecimal representation:

```
0000 1000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011
 0    8    1    0    0    0    0    3
```